# Show/hide div with a common class javascript no Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble trying to hide a number of div's that all have the same class. I would like to be able to click on a certain radio button that will show only the data that relates to that id. I have attempted to create a function to do this but can not get it to function properly. here is the fiddle i have been working on https://jsfiddle.net/uncj8wzf/

```
function hide_row(staff){
    if (staff == "manager"){
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("manager").style.display == "block")
           {document.querySelectorAll("employee").style.display = "none"}
        }
        else if (staff == "employee") {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName("manager").style.display == "none";)
            {document.querySelectorAll("employee").style.display = "block";}
        }            
        else if (staff == "all"){
           document.querySelectorAll("manager").style.display = "block";
           document.querySelectorAll("employee").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

```
<form>
<input type="radio"  onclick= "hide_row('manager')">manager<br>
<input type="radio"  onclick= "hide_row('employee')">employee<br>
<input type="radio"  onclick= "hide_row('all')">all
</form>

<div class="manager">manger text</div>
<div class="manager">manger text</div>
<div class="manager">manger text</div>
<div class="manager">manger text</div>


<div class="employee">employee text</div>
<div class="employee">employee text</div>
<div class="employee">employee text</div>
<div class="employee">employee text</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few parts of your code that make no sense to me.

Why the if statements in the hide_row function? Specifically

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("manager").style.display == "block")
```

And

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("manager").style.display == "none";)
```

Surely you just want to assign those displays, not check them, right? (Also that semi-colon shouldn't be there)

The results fo getElementsByClassName, or querySelectorAll are arrays. You'd need to loop through the results to assign the display value.

Lastly, don't forget to give your radio buttons the same `name` attribute so that they deselect the other buttons in the group.

Here's a snippet with it working:

```js
let managerDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("manager");
let employeeDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("employee");
let allDivs = [...managerDivs, ...employeeDivs];

function hide_row(staff) {

  // reveal all the divs, then hide those that need to be hidden
  for (let el of allDivs) {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }

  if (staff == "manager") {
    for (let el of employeeDivs) {
      el.style.display = "none";
    }
  } else if (staff == "employee") {
    for (let el of managerDivs) {
      el.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="showHide" onclick= "hide_row('manager')">manager<br>
<input type="radio" name="showHide" onclick= "hide_row('employee')">employee<br>
<input type="radio" name="showHide" onclick= "hide_row('all')">all
</form>

<div class="manager">manger text</div>
<div class="manager">manger text</div>
<div class="manager">manger text</div>
<div class="manager">manger text</div>


<div class="employee">employee text</div>
<div class="employee">employee text</div>
<div class="employee">employee text</div>
<div class="employee">employee text</div>
```